# Need to fix the powerplay of Snake and Ladder Game

Tags: python

I am currently trying to write code for **Snake and Ladder**
and Got stuck at below scenario.

Where I need to add second point check-in my code not getting

**My Need :**

- If game starts first time check only once for both player are the dice thrown are their in `powerupladder` or not. If their then assign the score of that `key -> value (score)` to the players

**for eg:**

```
powerupladder = { 4:56 , 12:50 , 14:55 , 22:58 , 41:79 , 54:88 }
player 1 -> dice thrown -> 4  -> 4 in powerupladder -> ply_1_score = 56 
Same applicable for both players
```

- Suppose the player 2 as previous score `6` and up till now he is not went through any ladder.
  Luckily the dice thrown was `4` so the score should be `6+4 = 10` and not  `4 -> 56 + 6 -> 62`

**Issue :**

If you look at the below output. The 8th line where powerup is mentioned

```
powerupladder = { 4:56 , 12:50 , 14:55 , 22:58 , 41:79 , 54:88 }
powerupladder_ply_2 = copy.deepcopy(powerupladder)

  1    Player 2 --> Bob with score --> 5   --> Dice  --->  5
  4    Player 2 --> Bob with score --> 7   --> Dice  --->  2
  6    Player 2 --> Bob with score --> 10  --> Dice  --->  3
  8    Player 2 --> Bob with score --> 66  --> Dice  --->  4 --> Powerup  [ 56 + 10 ] : 66
```

As per the game the score of Bob should be `14 [ 10 + 4 ]`
But going into Powerup and checking `4:56` and then `56 + 10 : 66` it is happening

The powerup ladder I have written when the game starts for first time to check dice in `powerupladder` or not only once. But every dice is going through this `powerupladder`.

**My all game execution :**

```
 0    Player 1 --> Raj with score --> 2   --> Dice  --->  2
 1    Player 2 --> Bob with score --> 5   --> Dice  --->  5
 2    Player 1 --> Raj with score --> 56  --> Dice  --->  2 --> Powerup
 3    Player 1 --> Raj with score --> 60  --> Dice  --->  4
 4    Player 2 --> Bob with score --> 7   --> Dice  --->  2
 5    Player 1 --> Raj with score --> 65  --> Dice  --->  5
 6    Player 2 --> Bob with score --> 10  --> Dice  --->  3
 7    Player 1 --> Raj with score --> 66  --> Dice  --->  1
 8    Player 2 --> Bob with score --> 66  --> Dice  --->  4 --> Powerup
 9    Player 2 --> Bob with score --> 61  --> Dice  --->  5
 10   Player 1 --> Raj with score --> 68  --> Dice  --->  2
 11   Player 2 --> Bob with score --> 64  --> Dice  --->  3
 12   Player 1 --> Raj with score --> 72  --> Dice  --->  4
 13   Player 2 --> Bob with score --> 66  --> Dice  --->  2
 14   Player 1 --> Raj with score --> 73  --> Dice  --->  1
 15   Player 2 --> Bob with score --> 67  --> Dice  --->  1
 16   Player 1 --> Raj with score --> 78  --> Dice  --->  5
 17   Player 2 --> Bob with score --> 69  --> Dice  --->  2
 18   Player 1 --> Raj with score --> 80  --> Dice  --->  2
 19   Player 2 --> Bob with score --> 74  --> Dice  --->  5
 20   Player 1 --> Raj with score --> 83  --> Dice  --->  3
 21   Player 2 --> Bob with score --> 79  --> Dice  --->  5
 22   Player 1 --> Raj with score --> 88  --> Dice  --->  5
 23   Player 2 --> Bob with score --> 80  --> Dice  --->  1
 24   Player 1 --> Raj with score --> 94  --> Dice  --->  6
 25   Player 2 --> Bob with score --> 86  --> Dice  --->  6
 26   Player 1 --> Raj with score --> 95  --> Dice  --->  1
 27   Player 2 --> Bob with score --> 91  --> Dice  --->  5
 28   Player 1 --> Raj with score --> 98  --> Dice  --->  3
 29   Player 2 --> Bob with score --> 92  --> Dice  --->  1
 30   Player 1 --> Raj with score --> 100 --> Dice  --->  2
      Reached the final destination... player Raj with score : 100
```

**Code :**

```
import random , time , sys , copy

# Creating a list to store the player who will be playing first and next second 
lst_of_palyers = ['Bob','Raj']


# Setting Ladder 
powerupladder = { 4:56 , 12:50 , 14:55 , 22:58 , 41:79 , 54:88 }
powerupladder_ply_1 = copy.deepcopy(powerupladder)
powerupladder_ply_2 = copy.deepcopy(powerupladder)

flag = 0

while True:
  

  if flag == 0:

    dice_rolled_ply_1 = random.randint(1,6)

    if dice_rolled_ply_1 in powerupladder_ply_1:                           
        player_1_score = ply1 + powerupladder_ply_1[dice_rolled_ply_1]      
        ply1 = powerupladder_ply_1[dice_rolled_ply_1]                      
        del powerupladder_ply_1[dice_rolled_ply_1]
        print(f'Player 1 --> {lst_of_palyers[i]} with score --> {player_1_score}  --> Dice  --->  {dice_rolled_ply_1} --> Powerup')
        flag = 0

    else:
      
      player_1_score = ply1 + dice_rolled_ply_1  

      if player_1_score in powerupladder_ply_1:
        ply1 = powerupladder_ply_1[player_1_score]
        del powerupladder_ply_1[player_1_score]
        player_1_score = ply1
        print(f'Player 1 --> {lst_of_palyers[i]} with score --> {player_1_score}  --> Dice  --->  {dice_rolled_ply_1} --> Powerup')
        flag = 0
      else:
        ply1 = ply1 + dice_rolled_ply_1
        print(f'Player 1 --> {lst_of_palyers[i]} with score --> {player_1_score}  --> Dice  --->  {dice_rolled_ply_1}')
        flag=1

          

  else:

    dice_rolled_ply_2 = random.randint(1,6)

    if dice_rolled_ply_2 in powerupladder_ply_2:                           
        
        player_2_score = ply2 + powerupladder_ply_2[dice_rolled_ply_2]      
        ply2 = powerupladder_ply_2[dice_rolled_ply_2]                      
        del powerupladder_ply_2[dice_rolled_ply_2]
        print(f'Player 2 --> {lst_of_palyers[i+1]} with score --> {player_2_score}  --> Dice  --->  {dice_rolled_ply_2} --> Powerup')
        flag = 1

    else:
 
      player_2_score = ply2 + dice_rolled_ply_2  

      if player_2_score in powerupladder_ply_2:
        ply2 = powerupladder_ply_2[player_2_score]
        del powerupladder_ply_2[player_2_score]
        player_2_score = ply2
        print(f'Player 2 --> {lst_of_palyers[i+1]} with score --> {player_2_score}  --> Dice  --->  {dice_rolled_ply_2}')
        flag = 1
      else:
        ply2 = ply2 + dice_rolled_ply_2
        print(f'Player 2 --> {lst_of_palyers[i+1]} with score --> {player_2_score}  --> Dice  --->  {dice_rolled_ply_2}')
        flag=0

  if ply1 >= maxCnt:
    print("")
    print(f'Reached the final destination... player {lst_of_palyers[i]} with score : {ply1}')
    break;
  elif ply2 >= maxCnt:
    print("")
    print(f'Reached the final destination... player {lst_of_palyers[i+1]} with score : {ply2}')
    break;
  else:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to delete the
`if dice_rolled_ply_1 in powerupladder_ply_1:` and `if dice_rolled_ply_2 in powerupladder_ply_2:` with their `True` part as they don't do anything useful and also introduce the bug you mention in your question.

So your code should look like this:

```
import random, time, sys, copy

# Creating a list to store the player who will be playing first and next second
lst_of_palyers = ["Bob", "Raj"]


# Setting Ladder
powerupladder = {4: 56, 12: 50, 14: 55, 22: 58, 41: 79, 54: 88}
powerupladder_ply_1 = copy.deepcopy(powerupladder)
powerupladder_ply_2 = copy.deepcopy(powerupladder)

flag = 0

while True:

    if flag == 0:

        dice_rolled_ply_1 = random.randint(1, 6)

        player_1_score = ply1 + dice_rolled_ply_1

        if player_1_score in powerupladder_ply_1:
            ply1 = powerupladder_ply_1[player_1_score]
            del powerupladder_ply_1[player_1_score]
            player_1_score = ply1
            print(
                f"Player 1 --> {lst_of_palyers[i]} with score --> {player_1_score}  --> Dice  --->  {dice_rolled_ply_1} --> Powerup"
            )
            flag = 0
        else:
            ply1 = ply1 + dice_rolled_ply_1
            print(
                f"Player 1 --> {lst_of_palyers[i]} with score --> {player_1_score}  --> Dice  --->  {dice_rolled_ply_1}"
            )
            flag = 1

    else:

        dice_rolled_ply_2 = random.randint(1, 6)

        player_2_score = ply2 + dice_rolled_ply_2

        if player_2_score in powerupladder_ply_2:
            ply2 = powerupladder_ply_2[player_2_score]
            del powerupladder_ply_2[player_2_score]
            player_2_score = ply2
            print(
                f"Player 2 --> {lst_of_palyers[i+1]} with score --> {player_2_score}  --> Dice  --->  {dice_rolled_ply_2}"
            )
            flag = 1
        else:
            ply2 = ply2 + dice_rolled_ply_2
            print(
                f"Player 2 --> {lst_of_palyers[i+1]} with score --> {player_2_score}  --> Dice  --->  {dice_rolled_ply_2}"
            )
            flag = 0

    if ply1 >= maxCnt:
        print("")
        print(
            f"Reached the final destination... player {lst_of_palyers[i]} with score : {ply1}"
        )
        break
    elif ply2 >= maxCnt:
        print("")
        print(
            f"Reached the final destination... player {lst_of_palyers[i+1]} with score : {ply2}"
        )
        break
    else:
        pass
```